# PHP using print_r with <pre> tag not working

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying that my code will output  like this with the pre tag:

[image]

but he give me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ')'
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\basics\echo.php on line 25

And this is the code:

```
<?php

    $levels = array(
        1 => array( 'name' => 'level 1', 'desc' => 'This is the first level' ),
        2 => array('name' => 'level 2', 'desc' => 'youve made it to level 2!',
        3 => array('name' => 'level 3', 'desc' => 'The last level'
      )
```

but its not working.

Comment: This code won't produce this error! You don't have an echo anywhere! Show us your full code!

Comment: `on line 25` so show us line 25 and the few lines before

Comment: As above, the code provided won't give that error (though will cause it if your next line is the echo). You are missing 2 ending brackets and a semi-colon.

Comment: sorry for that, was a mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the image  provided, code will look this way

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($levels);
echo "</pre>";
```

Check your code for syntax errors

Comment: ok! i chacked that and its now working,

Comment: @TalRod OK good to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code . i will work.
<?php

    $levels = array(
        1 => array( 'name' => 'level 1', 'desc' => 'This is the first level' ),
        2 => array('name' => 'level 2', 'desc' => 'youve made it to level 2!'),
        3 => array('name' => 'level 3', 'desc' => 'The last level')
      );
      echo"<pre>";
      print_r($levels);
      echo "</pre>";
      ?>
```